# How can I convert programmatically text to prc/mobi file?

Tags: c#, java, text, kindle

How can I convert programmatically text to prc/mobi file?
Exists any framework for c# or java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 tools Calibre, eBookTools, and mobiperl. 
Calibre is written in Python and has a GUI, and the other two are written in perl.

You can use those if there is no real need to convert the documents from your app.
Or start a proces from your app to execute a shell to process them